# How to group records on basis of specific date range?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, group-by

Need to group records on day basis in specific date range? I mean i have two dates : start_date and end date and between that date i need to group record on day basis. Ex: date range: 06-11-2019 and 07-15-2019 now i need all records in group by: [date: 06-11-2019, count: 5], [date: 06-12-2019, count: 5], [date: 06-13-2019, count: 5], [date: 06-14-2019, count: 5], [date: 06-15-2019, count: 5]

Comment: Use `group_by`. eg: `Array.group_by {|i| i == "something"}` . See [link](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/group_by)

Comment: group_by not active_records method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[groupdate](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) is nice gem to consider for your scenario.

You can write your query like below,

```
User.where("created_at > :start_date and created_at < :end_date", start_date: "Your start date here", end_date: "Your end date here").group_by_day(:created_at).count
```

Here I have considered `created_at` column to group by but you can use any datetime column you want.

Comment: I also need to include start_date and end_date in response even if its record count is zero

Comment: Then you should use <= and >= in query.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this by using the ActiveRecord group method like:

```
def all_users_by_date
    ["date: #{User.group("DATE(created_at)").first} count: #{User.count(:group => 'date(created_at)')}"]
end
```

I hope that helpful